# C# Firewall not working at Windows 7

Tags: c#, windows-7

Presently I am working in a Firewall project. First I downloaded a Firewall project from codeproject http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/firewallpapi.aspx which was in C++. So I made a dll from that code and called it from C# project. Its working perfectly . But in Windows 7 it is not working. Can anyone give me any hint, why it is not working at windows 7.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps because [the API has changed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366510%28VS.85%29.aspx):

> "By providing a simpler development
>   platform, Windows Filtering Platform
>   is designed to replace previous packet
>   filtering technologies such as
>   Transport Driver Interface (TDI)
>   filters, Network Driver Interface
>   Specification (NDIS) filters, and
>   Winsock Layered Service Providers
>   (LSP). Starting in Windows Server 2008
>   and Windows Vista, the firewall hook
>   and the filter hook drivers are not
>   available; applications that were
>   using these drivers should use Windows
>   Filtering Platform instead."

Answer (score 0):

Compile it for Windows 7 (32/ 64 Bit).

Check Event Viewer for any permission denied exception internally by windows.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to require elevation (User Account Control) but the app does not have a proper manifest so the elevation window never shos up.

Try Right Click -> Run As Admin and see if it works then.

Answer (score 0):

@Stuart Dunkeld I found a solution in Codeproject. 
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/PacketFilter.aspx